# Is there a method to set the replyTo header of an email using Exchange Web Service (EWS)?

Tags: java, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have been using the Exchange Web Service EWS v2.0 API for email processing in a Java based web application. I am trying to explore the options to set the Reply-To header using this but there does not seem to be any way to achieve this. Is there any possibility to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably all you need is to add your address to the [EmailMessage.ReplyTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage.replyto?view=exchange-ews-api#microsoft-exchange-webservices-data-emailmessage-replyto) collection.

C# Examples:

```
emailMessage.ReplyTo.Add(new EmailAddress("someone@sample.com"));
emailMessage.ReplyTo.Add("someone@sample.com");
```

Java Examples (ews-java-api):

```
emailMessage.getReplyTo().add(new EmailAddress("someone@example.com"));
emailMessage.getReplyTo().add("someone@example.com");
```

Comment: It appears that this is a read-only property and cannot be set.

Comment: @AnjanBaradwaj The property itself is read-only. But it is an `EmailAddressCollection` and that means that you can `Add(EmailAddress)` to the collection.

Comment: could you help me with an example on how to set it on an `EmailMessage` object?

Comment: In C# its `emailMessage.ReplyTo.Add(new EmailAddress("someone@sample.com"));` or even `emailMessage.ReplyTo.Add("someone@sample.com");`. With Java ([ews-java-api](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api)) its either `emailMessage.getReplyTo().add(new EmailAddress("someone@example.com"));` or `emailMessage.getReplyTo().add("someone@example.com");`

Comment: thanks @ThomasKläger this should answer my question. I have accepted this answer as I have found your comment under it useful!

Answer (score 0):

This Java code has worked for me to reply for recipient.

```
PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties,ItemSchema.Body,ItemSchema.Subject,ItemSchema.Attachments, EmailMessageSchema.ParentFolderId);
EmailMessage beforeMessage = EmailMessage.bind(service, item.getId(), propSet);
ResponseMessage responseMessage = new ResponseMessage(beforeMessage,ResponseMessageType.Reply);
MessageBody bodyPrefix = new MessageBody();
 bodyPrefix.setBodyType(BodyType.HTML);
 bodyPrefix.setText("replied reminder 02");
 responseMessage.setBodyPrefix(bodyPrefix);
 
List<EmailAddress> toRecipients = new ArrayList<EmailAddress>(){
            {
                add(new EmailAddress("yatesh.chauhan@sample.com"));
            }
        };
 responseMessage.getToRecipients()
                .addEmailRange(toRecipients.iterator());

 responseMessage.sendAndSaveCopy();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).